AWS_S3 Extension in Aurora PostgreSQL
What are all the file formats are supported in AWS_S3 Extension (Import and Export). In AWS documentation its mentioned as CSV,TXT and Zip. Does it support any other Format? Can we have any other format except(CSV, Text) under zip file?
I can import or export csv and txt format. I want to store the file in Parquet format. Is it possible to import and export data in Parquet format.

Postgresql in general doesn't understand Parquet files.
The aws_s3 extension uses the PostgreSQL COPY command. Therefore, any FORMAT commands valid for COPY will work with aws_s3.
The documentation says:

FORMAT: Selects the data format to be read or written: text, csv (Comma Separated Values), or binary. The default is text.

I did find GitHub - pgspider/parquet_s3_fdw: ParquetS3 Foreign Data Wrapper for PostgresSQL, but that doesn't seem applicable to Postresql in Amazon RDS.
